# How to make an AJAX request and fetch a PHP script on the same page?

Tags: php, ajax

For some reason, I need to pass an `ID` via AJAX to a PHP function on the same page and run a query and return the result back to AJAX which would then append the final result into a `div`.

As I did some research, I came across this solution, but there are some shortcomings with it.

1. `function1($_GET['id']);**//not getting the id's value**`
2. `echo "This is function 1 AND id=".$param;**//this string must be
   passed back to the previous ajax request.**`

**AJAX request (efund.phtml)**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'efund.phtml',
    data:"function_to_call=0?id"+cl[3], 
    success: function(data){
        // alert('successful');    
    }
});
```

**PHP (efund.phtml)**

```
switch ($_GET['function_to_call']) {
    case 0:
        function1($_GET['id']); // not getting the id's value
        break;

    case 1: 
        function2();
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

//And your functions. 

function function1($param) {
    echo "This is function 1 AND id=".$param; // This string must be passed back to the previous AJAX request.
}

function function2() {
    echo "This is function 2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to communicate between server/client tends to be to use XML or JSON, for your case I recommend you use [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "efund.phtml",
  data: { function_to_call: 0, id: cl[3] }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( msg );
    alert( "ID obtained from server is " + obj.id );
  });
```

And then in the server get them using:

```
$_GET['function_to_call']    // To obtain 'function_to_call' param
$_GET['id']                  // To obtain 'id' param
```

To send information back as response from the server I recommend you, use the same approach and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) for parse an array as JSON and return it using:

in your case for function1 it would be:

```
function function1($param) {
         return json_encode(array ( "id" => $param ) );
    }
```

Also, maybe you should consider if you should use GET or POST for the Http request. You can see more information about it here:
www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Edit:
If you have problems with the ajax request and you want to check if the ajax request is executed correctly modify the Ajax code like this:

```
  $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "efund.phtml",
      data: { function_to_call: 0, id: cl[3] }
    }).fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
    }).always(function() {
       alert( "complete" );
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( msg );
        alert( "ID obtained from server is " + obj.id );
      });
```

Comment: I can see your code make sense, it supposed to work but it doesn't. I think the value for $_GET['id']; is not passed / retrieved. Nothing happens when I invoke the ajax call.

Comment: Please can you go to the developer tool of the browser and take a look to:
1. Console tab to see if some error appear.
2. Network tab to see if the http request to 'efund.phtml' is made when the Ajax request is invoked.

Comment: the call made to the page correctly, however, I see this error: <h2>Invalid URL: adminpteb/efund/efund.phtml</h2>. I'm using magento and I think it doesn't allow a page simply fetched like this?

Comment: I had not use magento, but I think the error means that it can not find the URL where you want to send the request. Try change the url param in the Ajax request to "/efund.phtml".

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data:"function_to_call=0?id"+cl[3],
```

to

```
data: {function_to_call: 0,id : cl[3]},
```

in this case `data` work as object and it is easy to fetch value.

According to your only first condition called every time because you are passing `function_to_call=0`